# Check Empty System.IO.FileStream is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, memorystream

What i am trying to do is return a message box whenever a user click the button without uploading an image into the FileStream.

```
 FileStream stream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(stream);
        images = brs.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@images", images));


        MessageBox.Show("Upload complete");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

The program shows the "empty path name is not legal" error. How do I check for empty path name and return a message box?

Comment: What exactly is your error (ie is it a compile error, a runtime exception, if an exception what is the actual exception, or is it something else?) and on which line? If its on the first line where you are generating a file stream from a path is it not as easy as just checking that your `imgLocation` is not empty?

Comment: Having just checked passing `""` in for imgLocation will generate an ArgumentException with the message "Empty path name is not legal.". So where exactly are you having trouble? The message seems pretty clear on what your problem is. Do you not know how to check if a string is empty? Are you having some other problem with this conditional logic?

Comment: `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgLocation)) MessageBox.Show("Empty path");`

Answer (score 1):

You could do multiple checks here:

1. Check if string is empty:

   ```
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgLocation)) MessageBox.Show("Invalid path");
   ```
2. After check you can load the location in FileInfo class:

   ```
   FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
   ```

then check multiple things:

```
   if(file.Exists) //Check file's existence
   if(file.Length == 0) //Check if file is not empty
```

before operating on the file.

You can also check: (if you want to skip file.Length)

```
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    if(stream.Length==0) //check if stream is empty
```